# Error reading back from S3 immediately after writing

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-s3

Sometimes, with my spark program on AWS, if I write the dataframe to S3, and then read it back, I get errors like

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: 
No such file or directory 
's3://mypath/part-00000-f788e0f4-2498-4230-85b0-30cab97fc2ea-c000.snappy.parquet'
```

But when I take a look, the file is clearly there. I ran into this once before and resolved it by putting a sleep for 3 seconds between the write and read back. Does anyone know what is going on here? I think in terms of filesystems, thinking of s3 as a network file system, is there some way to sync my view of the file system before I do a read back? Maybe I should sleep 3 seconds, and then execute a `aws s3 ls s3://mypath` command?

Comment: You'll want to read about the [Amazon S3 Data Consistency Model](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/Introduction.html#ConsistencyModel) as it is not like a file system exactly.

Comment: If you are on Amazon EMR look into EMRFS Consistent View https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-plan-consistent-view.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because of Eventual Consistency of S3. This is a very common problem.

I can think of two ways to solve this problem -

1. Wait for some time after the write operation is complete and before starting the read operation. This is what you are already doing.
2. Use S3Guard. [This article](https://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2017/08/introducing-s3guard-s3-consistency-for-apache-hadoop/) explains in detail on how s3guard works and how it helps in preventing EC issues.